How can I use a relay and diodes to reverse the polarity to a electromagnet?
I am trying to make a solenoid using a motor, relay, and 12-volt battery. I have everything working, but it only goes one way. I want it to reverse the polarity when the relay is open. Will it work if I connect the NO contact to one magnet terminal, the NC contact to the other, and the ground to both? Do I need diodes on the relay terminals to keep them from shorting out?

The following circuit will reverse the polarity of the electromagnet when the relay coil is energized.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Here is some good advice from jp314

Be cautious about arcing as the relay contacts open. You can alleviate this by putting 2 (high current) zener diodes in series (with opposing polarities) across the electromagnet. Use Zeners >> your 12 V supply. –
jp314


Be cautious about arcing as the relay contacts open. You can alleviate this by putting 2 (high current) zener diodes in series (with opposing polarities) across the electromagnet. Use Zeners >> your 12 V supply.

If you want to switch the polarity with a relay what you need is a DPDT relay.
This is Double Pole (two common connections) and Double Throw (two switched connections per pole).
By connecting the supply voltage to the throws and the load to the poles you can have the polarity reverse as shown in these diagrams. Each pole will be connected to either the throw connected to positive or the one connected to negative, energizing the relay then connects them to the opposite throws, reversing the polarity.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
